# What are some good Perakim to learn over the summer with kids in camp?

Tags: talmud-gemara

Something interesting, engaging, with some depth for the kids more advanced. A perek of Gemara not usually covered in school.

All ideas welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: To answer, you'd have to know a) what they usually learn in school, and b) how many kids and classes. The camp I went to learned a different gemara in every grade. 5th was Arvei Pesachim and sixth was Tefillas HaShachar.

Comment: "Something ... with some depth" - don't all chapters of gemara qualify?

Comment: @mbloch at least we can be quite sure they're all interesting

Comment: @DoubleAA then what it remains is « engaging for kids ». My guess is the teacher is at least 80% of the answer here so there doesn’t remain a lot of the question for us to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to learn the last (9th) Perek of Brachos (called Ha'Roeh) with kids in camp. Part of my teaching was to give a "semichah" test to the students regarding dream interpretation.

Another favorite choice of mine was Perek "Chelek" which is officially the last Perek in Sanhedrin.

It should be presented seriously, but with a fun flair geared to the summer atmosphere.

Just my own choice and experience.

Many camps not willing to explore such "Aggadata" Gemara as a main course even in the summer turn to Masechta Sukkah as a favorite.

I would go for the last two Perakim of Sukkah for a "summer" course, but the whole thing can be seriously done if you have more seder time and good picture books.

I hope this helps.